# Unix Command to delete siblings and parent directory of a given file

Tags: unix, command

I have a directory structure like this

```
/home
   /dir-1
      some-file.php
   /dir-2
      sibling.php
      target-file.php
   /dir-3
   /dir-4
      other-sibling.php
      sibling.php
      target-file.php
   /dir-5
      target-file.php
```

I need to target all directories containing the file "`target-file.php`" and remove those directories with its contents. In my structure, the final result wanted is:

```
/home
   /dir-1
      some-file.php
   /dir-3
```

I am trying:

```
rm -rf /home/*/target-file.php
```

But it is only removing that file (`target-file.php`) and not the siblings or the parent directory.

Please help

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name target-file.php -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' line
do
    echo "$line"
    /bin/rm -fr "$(dirname "$line")"
done
```

- Using `find` with `while` like this ensure it will work with all filenames (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- You can run `find . -type f -name target-file.php -print` to see the list of files.
- `dirname` removes the filename so you are left with only the directory names.
- `/bin/rm -fr` deletes the directories.
- you can comment the `echo` line, this was just to show you the files / directories being processed.